# Why is this knockoutjs observableArray not causing UI update?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a feeling I'm missing something simple here, but just can't quite grok this.  Here is my script:

```
function FormDefinition()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Fields = ko.observableArray([new FieldDefinition()]);    
}

function FieldDefinition()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Name = "Test";
}
function ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.formDef = ko.observable(new FormDefinition());
    self.Name = "bob"
    self.addField = function(){
        this.formDef().Fields().push(new FieldDefinition());                    
    }            
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

and here is my markup:

```
<a data-bind="click: addField">Add</a><br/>
<span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
<ul data-bind="foreach: formDef().Fields">
    <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
</ul>​
```

and here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xSmr/

Expected behavior is that clicking 'Add' would cause the ui to update.  debugging reveals that addfield is getting called.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Fixed your fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/5xSmr/2/

```html
<a data-bind="click: AddField">Add</a><br/>
<span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
<ul data-bind="foreach: formDef().Fields()">
    <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
</ul>
```

```js
function FormDefinition()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Fields = ko.observableArray();    
}

function FieldDefinition()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Name = "Test";
}
function ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.formDef = ko.observable(new FormDefinition());
    self.Name = "bob"
    self.AddField = function(){
        this.formDef().Fields.push({Name:"test"});
    }            
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The main problem was that you were calling Fields() and not just Fields. Fields() return the unwrapped array and by pushing directly to it, ko would never know about it.

Comment: @Daniel I'd recommend marking this as the approved answer, as it provides both a working example and an explanation of _why_.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/Q6J6a/3/

**View**

```
<a href='#' data-bind="click: AddField">Add</a><br/>
<span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
<ul data-bind="foreach: formDef.Fields">
    <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
</ul>​
```

**Javascript**

```
var FormDefinition = function ()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Fields = ko.observableArray();    
}

var ViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.formDef = new FormDefinition();
    self.Name = ko.observable("bob");
    self.AddField = function(){
        self.formDef.Fields.push({Name:"test"});            
    }            
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

​

​

Comment: Some context would improve this answer.